# Understanding llvm-ir to assembly for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llc

I transform the following llvm-IR

```
; Function Attrs: noinline norecurse nounwind uwtable
define i32 @main() #0{
entry:
%sub = sub nsw i32 5, 3
%cmp = icmp slt i32 %sub, 3
br i1 %cmp, label %if.then, label %if.else

if.then:                                          ; preds = %entry
%mul = mul nsw i32 %sub, 2
br label %if.end

if.else:                                          ; preds = %entry
%sub1 = sub nsw i32 %sub, 3
br label %if.end

if.end:                                           ; preds = %if.else, 
%if.then
%y.0 = phi i32 [ %mul, %if.then ], [ %sub1, %if.else ]
%sub2 = sub nsw i32 %sub, %y.0
%add = add nsw i32 %sub, %y.0
ret i32 0
}
```

to assembly code for `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`
using `llc sample.ll`
generated assembly code:

```
    .text
    .file   "phi.cpp"
    .globl  main                    # -- Begin function main
    .p2align        4, 0x90
    .type   main,@function
main:                                   # @main
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:                                 # %entry
    pushq   %rbp
.Lcfi0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.Lcfi1:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
.Lcfi2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    testb   %al, %al
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
.Lfunc_end0:
    .size   main, .Lfunc_end0-main
    .cfi_endproc
                                    # -- End function
```

The register in the above code: `%rbp` is the base pointer, which points to the base of the current stack frame, and `%rsp` is the stack pointer, which points to the top of the current stack frame and operand are store in `%eax` and `%al` for arithmatic operation but in can't find the instruction where the value is load in `%eax` and `%al` register 
I also want to know

1. How llc is handling phi node on assembly level

Answer (score 1):

`lli` defaults to `-O2` and your code start with a constant expression `sub nsw i32 5, 3`. Thus, your function does, basically, nothing, and the only thing LLVM should keep is to nullify EAX.

If you run `lli -O0 your.ll`, you'll get much verbose code, that perform spills on stack and register loads.

BTW, there are a pair of passes called `mem2reg` and `reg2mem` that convert code back and forth code from SSA form. Specifically, these passes would convert `phi` nodes to branches and introduce explicit stores and loads in IR.